# webservice throws error System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

Here is how my 2 projects are

1. I have a class library project which consumes multiple webservices.
2. I have created a test project in VSTS and try to call one of those service

But I'm receiving System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException. In my Test Project I have added one app.config file and added endpoint as available in my Serviceclass library project app.config.

Could anyone have encounter same problem before. Please help.

Thanks,
Pritam

Comment: Post your config, contract name (fully qualified) and service class name (fully qualified) to find out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your service class library hosted in IIS? If so, you need to add the relevant info (everything in `<system.serviceModel>`) to your web.config.

Are you self-hosting the WCF service? Then the host application needs to have that info in its `app.config`.

You **cannot** just put that info into the service class library's `app.config` - that file will **not** be used by .NET - you need to put the info into the host application's `web.config` (for IIS) or `app.config` (if you self-host).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but check this:
- Maybe you have the endpoint twice in your app.config 
- App.config that should have endpoint configuration is the one in the testproject